# Getting enemy vehicle to follow player vehicle C++

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently building a game where the played drives a semi truck and is followed and attacked by enemy cars by attempted slamming. I got some help from one of my teachers on how to get the enemy to choose which direction to go in order to follow and attack the player. Upon implementing what she gave me I got weird behavior and feel like I'm missing something.

When I place an enemy car in game near the player and pass the player's position into the function the enemy car simply spins in circles. If I add velocity to it i drives in large circles. Generally it never chooses a direction to drive straight in.

After debugging it seems like my if statement doesn't ever resolve and upon every update it keeps trying to get back towards 0 but for some reason it can't.
I am not sure if the coordinates of the player are creating the issue or if my math calculations or going wonky.

```
void EnemySpeedy::playerTracking(float posX, float posY)
{
    //Direction choosing
    dir.x = posX - pos.x;
    dir.y = posY - pos.y;

    //plus maybe this?
    goalAngle = atan2f(dir.y, dir.x);

    //I think this is the problem code?//
    if (angle < goalAngle) angle -= sfw::getDeltaTime() * angularSpeed;
    else                   angle += sfw::getDeltaTime() * angularSpeed;


    //AI Movement alla adding velocity
    acc = speed;

    vel = vel + (acc - dragVel) * sfw::getDeltaTime();

    vel = std::fmaxf(0, vel);
    vel = std::fminf(vel, maxVel);

    pos = { pos.x + vel * cosf(angle * PI / 180) * sfw::getDeltaTime(),
            pos.y + vel * sinf(angle * PI / 180) * sfw::getDeltaTime() };
}
```

Comment: [ye olde steering behaviors...e](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/)

Answer (score 3):

`atan2f` returns radians, so your `goalAngle` is in the range [-Pi,Pi].

I don't know if your `angle` and the `angularSpeed` use the same metric, but when you calculate the `sinf` and `cosf` you are converting `angle` from degrees to radians.

I suggest to keep all your angles in radians and check them:

```
#include <cmath>

inline float normAngle ( float ang ) {
    return ang < -M_PI ? ang + 2.0*M_PI : ( ang > M_PI ? ang - 2.0*M_PI : ang);
}

inline float limitValue ( float x, float min, float max ) {
    return x < min ? min : ( x > max ? max : x );
}
```

Then, you can try this logic:

```
void EnemySpeedy::playerTracking(float posX, float posY)
{
    //Direction choosing, pos is a member of EnemySpeedy
    float dirX = posX - pos.x;
    float dirY = posY - pos.y;

    //Angle choosing; angle, angularSpeed and angularSpeedMax are members of EnemySpeedy
    float goalAngle = atan2(dirY, dirX);
    float difAngle = normAngle(angle - goalAngle);
    angularSpeed = limitValue(-difAngle,-angularSpeedMax,angularSpeedMax);
    float dt = sfw::getDeltaTime();
    angle = normAngle(angle + dt * angularSpeed);

    // Update speed; acc, vel, etc. are members of EnemySpeedy class
    // acc = speed;         // it seems odd to me...
    // vel = limitValue(vel + (acc - dragVel) * dt, 0.0, maxVel);
                         // what about:
    acc = (difAngle > 1.5 || difAngle < -1.5) ? -maxAcc/2.0 : maxAcc*(maxVel - vel)/maxVel;
    //          brake if direction is wrong, go to limit velocity otherwise
    acc = limitValue(acc, -maxAcc, maxAcc);
    vel = limitValue(vel + acc * dt, 0.0, maxVel);

    // Update position
    pos.x += vel * cos(angle) * dt;
    pos.y += vel * sin(angle) * dt;
}
```

Comment: The angle is which way the car is pointed, angular speed is how quickly it can rotate its angle.

Comment: @Andrew C Ward: Yes, I figured it out ;). I was wondering if you were using radians or degrees.

Comment: This code defiantly worked better, it at least chooses a direction and locks to it now. The next problem is that it always goes the same direction regardless of input change. Basically it won't follow the play but some arbitrary point it is constantly choosing. Any ideas?

Comment: @Andrew C Ward: Odd. Are you sure to pass the right values? How are the members of the EnemySpeedy class initialized? I assumed that pos, acc, vel, angle and angularSpeed are all class members, is it right?

Comment: @Andrew C Ward: Which direction does it choose?